# How to use Qlist to create a user profile model with about 15 different fields

Tags: qt

I know some professional developers are shaking there heads with disappointment... Im just trying to wrap my head around how to use Qlist to store multiple types of data within one table. And I know I will use QTableModel to set this data right? Building a billing app. Basic ideas or links will be fine... Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good read for the best practices for [Model/View Programming in Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html#model-classes).

The examples and links at the bottom of the above link are nice, too.

As for storing multiple types, I would look at [QVariant](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qvariant.html) and QSettings; using QVariant is referenced many times in the Model/View Programming in Qt.

QVariant is very robust and works well with many different types.  It is core in reading values out of QSettings.  Be sure to read the description of QSettings for more ideas.

```
    QBitArray    toBitArray () const
    bool         toBool () const
    QByteArray   toByteArray () const
    QChar        toChar () const
    QDate        toDate () const
    QDateTime    toDateTime () const
    double       toDouble ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
    QEasingCurve toEasingCurve () const
    float        toFloat ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
    QHash<QString, QVariant>    toHash () const
    int          toInt ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
    QLine        toLine () const
    QLineF       toLineF () const
    QList<QVariant>    toList () const
    QLocale      toLocale () const
    qlonglong    toLongLong ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
    QMap<QString, QVariant>    toMap () const
    QPoint       toPoint () const
    QPointF      toPointF () const
    qreal        toReal ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
    QRect        toRect () const
    QRectF       toRectF () const
    QRegExp      toRegExp () const
    QSize        toSize () const
    QSizeF       toSizeF () const
    QString      toString () const
    QStringList  toStringList () const
    QTime        toTime () const
    uint         toUInt ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
    qulonglong   toULongLong ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
    QUrl         toUrl () const
```

Another good option is QString.  It has a number of built in conversions also:

```
    QByteArray    toAscii () const
    QString       toCaseFolded () const
    double        toDouble ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
    float         toFloat ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
    int           toInt ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 10 ) const
    QByteArray    toLatin1 () const
    QByteArray    toLocal8Bit () const
    long          toLong ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 10 ) const
    qlonglong     toLongLong ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 10 ) const
    QString       toLower () const
    short         toShort ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 10 ) const
    std::string   toStdString () const
    std::wstring  toStdWString () const
    uint          toUInt ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 10 ) const
    ulong         toULong ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 10 ) const
    qulonglong    toULongLong ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 10 ) const
    ushort        toUShort ( bool * ok = 0, int base = 10 ) const
    QVector<uint> toUcs4 () const
    QString       toUpper () const
    QByteArray    toUtf8 () const
    int           toWCharArray ( wchar_t * array ) const
```

When saving numerical values to a QString, be sure to use QString::number().